# MongoDB Schema: Array with multiple fields?

Tags: mongodb, schema, database

I'm trying to create a schema for users to store their favorite shoes. Right now, I have the following schema:

```
local: {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
}
```

How do I add an array of shoes such that when the user clicks on a button, the database will add the shoe brand and size to the User object? So something like:

favorite_shoes: { brand: xxxx size: xxxx, brand: xxxxx size: xxxxxx}

for each user. How would I do this/how would the schema look like?

Comment: Just insert `favorite_shoes` in the user map, `db.users.update({usernam: "username"}, {$set: {favorite_shoes: ...}})`, `mongodb` has no schemas.

Comment: But don't I need to set fields for it when it initializes the database? Also I need this to be an array of brands to sizes?

Comment: Not at all, `mongodb` is a schema-less document database, you can insert maps of any structure. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/introduction/

Comment: Make it an array of maps `[{brand: xxx, size:123}, ...]`

Comment: So would the updated schema look like this:

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    }
    favorite_shoes : [{
     name    : String, 
     size    : Number, 
    }]
});

Answer (score 1):

Your schema will look like this:

```
{
  usernam: String,
  email: String,
  password : String,
  favorite_shoes: [ { brand: String, size: Int}, {brand: String, size: Int} ]
}
```

You don't have to create `favorite_shoes` field beforehand. It will get created first time you set its value.

If you want to avoid shoes repeating in the list use `$addToSet`:

```
db.users.update({usernam: "username"}, {$addToSet: {favorite_shoes: { brand: "Adidas", size: 12 } }});
```